# Why html5lightbox doesn't work with angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, lightbox

I use html5lightbox to open images and pdf file in lightbox. Now I added angular.js and when click on a link, it takes me to enother page instead of opening it in a lightbox

```
var app =  angular.module('MyApp', []);

var tiles =
[
    {
        class: "fileTile",
        link: "images/9-credit-1.jpg",
        header: "ToDo List",
        content: "PDF File contains information about SAP sales and customers"
    },
    {
        class: "videoTile",
        link: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nfq3OC6B-CU",
        header: "Fiori Tutorial",
        content: "This Video contains information about SAP sales and customers"
    },
    {
        class: "fileTile",
        link: "images/canberra_hero_image_JiMVvYU.jpg",
        header: "A Random Image",
        content: "PDF File contains information about SAP sales and customers"
    },
    {
        class: "fileTile",
        link: "images/national-basketball-association-scoring-big-with-real-time-statistics-and-sap-hana.pdf?iframe=true",
        header: "National Basketboal Team",
        content: "PDF File contains information about SAP sales and customers"
    }
];


  app.controller("DisplayController", function($scope, $http){
     $scope.tiles = tiles;
  });
```

What can I do make html5lightbox working???

Comment: Create a codepen / plnkr

Comment: Here is the link http://codepen.io/Octtavius/pen/mPjaMy                                          But the light box will not work because I cannot upload  the html5lightbox package which is downloaded on my local computer only and not on codepen.

Comment: You can add external links 'settings' button top right.  Either host the file yourself or point to a public file.  A couple of pointers on your code.  1) You are mixing jQuery and Angular code in a not recommended way.  Direct DOM manipulation is not recommended.  Except in... -> 2) If you need to use a jQuery add in write a Directive to handle that and setup everything in the link function using the 'element' variable.   3) The code you show hardly does anything Angular, so why use Angular in the first place.  4) When giving an example it's best to boil it down to its essence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**angular-bootstrap-lightbox**](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox).Simply awesome.

Here is the Working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pEXXDYLl0NtkqupEXaJK)

***html***

```
<ul ng-controller="GalleryCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)">
      <img ng-src="{{image.thumbUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***JS (controller)***

```
angular.module('app').controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, Lightbox) {
  $scope.images = [
    {
      'url': '1.jpg',
      'caption': 'Optional caption',
      'thumbUrl': 'thumb1.jpg' // used only for this example
    },
    {
      'url': '2.gif',
      'thumbUrl': 'thumb2.jpg'
    },
    {
      'url': '3.png',
      'thumbUrl': 'thumb3.png'
    }
  ];

  $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
    Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
  };
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://compact.github.io/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/demo1/)

Comment: I know, I love it, but it doesn't work for me. To the code you posted in my html file I have this  <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-bootstrap-lightbox.css"><script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>   but it doesn't work. I also used other demos but no luck.

Comment: @Octtavius I have put a working plunker above.Please see that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally this angular lightbox works. I will try to use it instead of the html5lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is

```
data-lightbox
```

like identifier that means this link will be shown in lightbox..
If i remember truely you must give an attribute like this for lightbox like codes.

Or can you whare angular template/html that u are trying to use for.

Regards

Comment: Yes. the html5lightbox works perfect without angular. When I add angular, it doesn't work.     This is how it works  <a href="#" class="html5lightbox"">

Comment: Dear friend, if next answer doesnot work, please debug..
     for some runtime error.

regards

Comment: Sorry for that many questions. Would you know why instead of 'x' close icon it shows unreadable characters when open the light box. In you plunker it works, but on my machine, the next, previous, close buttons have some characters instead of icons? Appreciate your help